# How can I dynamically debug a malicious DLL?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, malware, dll, dynamic-analysis

English isn't my first language, So I will do my best )

I am trying to analyze some malware [NotPetya](https://github.com/ytisf/theZoo/blob/master/malwares/Binaries/Ransomware.Petrwrap/Ransomware.Petrwrap.zip) and I can run the malware by running :

`rundll32.exe notpetya.dll #1`

I am using Olly and trying to use the LoadDLL feature. I see where the DLL calls some of it's functions, however I am not able to follow and watch it work. I want to be able to debug this DLL and see what is happening as it's working.

As far as I can tell, there doesn't appear to be anything to obfuscate me from doing this.

I hope I have made this clear enough for people to understand. I don't require the answer to use OllyDBG , but I would like to be able to follow this DLL.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this existing answer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15796/161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing would be to find the entrypoint in the DLL, make a note of the byte at that location, and then replace it with an "int 3" (0xcc) instruction.  Then you can use a debugger to run the command-line that will cause the DLL to be loaded, and the debugger will regain control.  At that point, you can restore the replaced byte with the original value, and single-step or run to breakpoints that you set.

Comment: The answer.was similar. I realized that the dll had two entry points and the first entry just closes the application. Anyway, I just made some assembly that loaded the dll and pulled the exports from.jt and jmped to it. The int 3 helps stop on secondary entry.